# Как отучить Windows создавать папку "System Volume Information" на съемных носителях?

Tags: windows

Вопрос в заголовке. Я в курсе что это восстановление системы пишет, но нафига оно мне надо на съемных носителях не понимаю?

P.S. Сколько себя помню это работало на всех версиях винды.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Запускаем gpedit.msc
> 2. Переходим Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Search
> 3. Включаем политику 
>      Do not allow locations on removable drives to be added to libraries.

Через реестр можно сделать то же самое, если в

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
```

создать ключ

```
DisableRemovableDriveIndexing = 1.
```

[Источник](https://dentnt.windowsfaq.ru/?p=4245)

[Еще способ](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-system-volume-information-folder-usb)